# Debugging my if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I have decided to help my friends lose weight, I'm knew to coding and am trying to develop a program that calculates your BMI (Body mass index), however I'm a little confused with my if statements. They're not working how I would expect them to. Here is what I have got so far and looking at it I can't understand why it is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double weight;
    double height;
    double bmi;
    cout << "Enter weight in kilograms:\n";
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "Enter height in metres:\n";
    cin >> height;

    bmi = weight/(pow(height,2));

    if (bmi < 18.5) {
           cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Underweight range" << endl;
    }
    else {
     (bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9)
           cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Normal range" << endl;
    }

    else {
        (bmi > 25.0) && (bmi < 29.9)
           cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Normal range" << endl;
    }

    else (bmi > 30) {
           cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Obese range" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was told I could use else multiple times and I am thinking that it might be the source of the error, I do believe I am close.

Thank you.

Comment: Syntax is incorrect : use `if (cond) { ...} else if (cond2) { ... } else if (cond3) { ... } else { .... }`

Comment: @Garf365 awesome thanks, I'll give it a go now!

Comment: Why are there two `Normal range`s? What's the difference? Is one more `Normal` than the other?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
if (bmi < 18.5) {
       cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Underweight range" << endl;
}
// else bmi >= 18.5, no need to test it again
else if(bmi < 24.9) {
       cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Normal range" << endl;
}
else if(...) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just saying: What if bmi == 18.5?

Answer (score -2):

Your if-else syntax is wrong. It should be if(condition)-else if(other condition)-else, like this:

```
bmi = weight/(pow(height,2));

if (bmi < 18.5) {
       cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Underweight range" << endl;
}
else if ((bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9))
       cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Normal range" << endl;
}

else if ((bmi > 25.0) && (bmi < 29.9))
       cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Normal range" << endl;
}

else /*(bmi > 30)*/ {
       cout <<"Your BMI is " << bmi <<", which means you are in the Obese range" << endl;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: So bmi = 18.5 or 25.0 is obese?

Comment: Ugh. Think about what your comparison operators and values are doing. Checking for e.g. `< 18.5` and then `> 18.5` means that exact values e.g. `18.5` are not caught by any of your explicit conditional blocks and, therefore, erroneously get lumped into the final `else` clause. Equally, checking for e.g. `< 24.9` and then `> 25.0` means the entire `0.1` range of values `24.9 <= n <= 25.0` also fail to match and get relegated there. You need to fix the values being compared to, and use the correct operators to do the comparison.